# How to read and execute config.yaml file from scripted jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to stackoverflow as well as new to the coding part. I have usecase to read each block from the config file and execute the function using jenkins scripted pipeline (groovy script). Here's i have written down the pseudo code with series of parameters in configuration file. Also, jenkinsfile that will read the config file and look for action-type that should meet the value called "business-logic". if it meets, it should only execute the block of scripts using iteration mode that has the key/value "action-type: business-logic"

Here's my code:

ast-config.yaml

```
message: ""veracode policyscan"
  action-type: vc-policy-scan
  code-location: "policyscan.groovy"
  
message: "Deploy DAGs to S3"
  action-type: business-logic
  binary-action: "copyfilesS3.py"

message: "Deploy CIT-CDW Folder to S3 Bucket"
  action-type: business-logic
  binary-action: "copyfolderS3.py" 

message: "Deploy CIT-CDW Folder to EFS"
  action-type: business-logic
  binary-action: ""
```

jenkinsfile

```
node {
  //checkout scm
  get-client-code("git url'cit-cdw'")
  def conf = readProperties file: "ApplicationConfiguration/ast-config.yaml"
  for block in conf {
        execute-stage(block)
  }

def execute-stage(block) {
        if (block.message.action-type == "business-logic")
            stage(block.message){
                steps { script {
                    sh """#!/bin/bash
                    block.binary-action()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems your yaml file is invalid

```
block:
  message: ""veracode policyscan"
  action-type: vc-policy-scan
  code-location: "policyscan.groovy"
 
block:
  message: "Deploy DAGs to S3"
  action-type: business-logic
  binary-action: "copyfilesS3.py"
```

2. `readProperties` should fail to load yaml file, use `readYaml`

```
def conf = readYaml file: "ApplicationConfiguration/ast-config.yaml"
```

3. Should use [Groovy String Interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) to replace `binary-action` in below `sh` step

```
 sh """#!/bin/bash
  ${block.binary-action}
 """
```

Comment: Thanks @yong..This is quite helpful! quick check: if i go & update yaml file ``` block:
  message: ""veracode policyscan"
  action-type: vc-policy-scan
  code-location: "policyscan.groovy"
 
block:
  message: "Deploy DAGs to S3"
  action-type: business-logic
  binary-action: "copyfilesS3.py"

Comment: does it go to each block & execute ```binary-action script```  whose action-type == "business-logic" ```if (block.message.action-type == "business-logic")```